# Understanding and working with nested inductive definitons in coq

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to prove `insert_SearchTree`, a theorem about the preservation of a binary search tree after an insertion relation, below.  I'm not sure how to use the induction hypothesis which relies on the nested Inductive definitions, namely `SearchTree`'s single constructor calls on `SearchTree'`.  Once I instantiate and invert the IH, though, we are given an arguement `hi0` which is incomparable to `k`?

```
  ....
  H1 : SearchTree' 0 (insert k0 v0 l) hi0
  H2 : k0 < k
  ============================
  SearchTree' 0 (insert k0 v0 l) k
```

Is my approach to this proof flawed, or is there a trick to make them comparable?  I had thought  to try to prove something like

```
 Theorem insert_SearchTree'':
  forall k v t hi,
   SearchTree' 0 t hi -> SearchTree' 0 (insert k v t) hi .
Proof.
```

but after attempting I realized this is not equivalent (and I think unproveable, although I'm not sure)...  Any advice is welcome. Most of the code is auxiliary, and I included it based on the advice that  questions be stand-alone.

```
Require Export Coq.Arith.Arith.
Require Export Coq.Arith.EqNat.
Require Export Coq.omega.Omega.

Notation  "a >=? b" := (Nat.leb b a)
                          (at level 70, only parsing) : nat_scope.
Notation  "a >? b"  := (Nat.ltb b a)
                       (at level 70, only parsing) : nat_scope.
Notation " a =? b"  := (beq_nat a b)
                       (at level 70) : nat_scope.

Print reflect.

Lemma beq_reflect : forall x y, reflect (x = y) (x =? y).
Proof.
  intros x y.
  apply iff_reflect. symmetry.  apply beq_nat_true_iff.
Qed.

Lemma blt_reflect : forall x y, reflect (x < y) (x <? y).
Proof.
  intros x y.
  apply iff_reflect. symmetry. apply Nat.ltb_lt.
Qed.

Lemma ble_reflect : forall x y, reflect (x <= y) (x <=? y).
Proof.
  intros x y.
  apply iff_reflect. symmetry. apply Nat.leb_le.
Qed.

Hint Resolve blt_reflect ble_reflect beq_reflect : bdestruct.

Ltac bdestruct X :=
  let H := fresh in let e := fresh "e" in
   evar (e: Prop);
   assert (H: reflect e X); subst e;
    [eauto with bdestruct
    | destruct H as [H|H];
       [ | try first [apply not_lt in H | apply not_le in H]]].

Section TREES.
Variable V : Type.
Variable default: V.

Definition key := nat.

Inductive tree : Type :=
 | E : tree
 | T: tree -> key -> V -> tree -> tree.

Inductive SearchTree' : key -> tree -> key -> Prop :=
| ST_E : forall lo hi, lo <= hi -> SearchTree' lo E hi
| ST_T: forall lo l k v r hi,
    SearchTree' lo l k ->
    SearchTree' (S k) r hi ->
    SearchTree' lo (T l k v r) hi.

Inductive SearchTree: tree -> Prop :=
| ST_intro: forall t hi, SearchTree' 0 t hi -> SearchTree t.

Fixpoint insert (x: key) (v: V) (s: tree) : tree :=
 match s with
 | E => T E x v E
 | T a y v' b => if  x <? y then T (insert x v a) y v' b
                        else if y <? x then T a y v' (insert x v b)
                        else T a x v b
 end.

Theorem insert_SearchTree:
  forall k v t,
   SearchTree t -> SearchTree (insert k v t).
Proof.
  clear default.
  intros.
  generalize dependent v.
  generalize dependent k.
  induction H.
  induction H.
  - admit.
  - intros.
    specialize (IHSearchTree'1 k0 v0).
    inversion IHSearchTree'1. 
    subst.
    simpl.
    bdestruct (k0 <? k).
    apply (ST_intro _ hi0 ).
    constructor.
    admit.

End TREES.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is currently too weak when you start `induction`. At the beginning of the second case, the goal looks like this:

```
  H : SearchTree' lo l k
  H0 : SearchTree' (S k) r hi
  IHSearchTree'1 : forall (k : key) (v : V), SearchTree (insert k v l)
  IHSearchTree'2 : forall (k : key) (v : V), SearchTree (insert k v r)
  ============================
  forall (k0 : key) (v0 : V), SearchTree (insert k0 v0 (T l k v r))
```

and the high-level idea to go on is to combine `H` and `IHSearchTree'2`, or `H0` and `IHSearchTree'1`, depending on which side the insertion goes. But this is impossible because the `SearchTree` predicate in the two `IH` assumptions is not *compositional*: knowing only that `insert k0 v0 l` is a search tree does not help to know whether a tree containing it, `T (insert k0 v0 l) k v r`, is also a search tree. So the proof doesn't go through.

When putting search trees together, we don't just want to know that something is a search tree. We also want to know some bounds on the keys (here in particular, they must be bounded by `k`). This is what the auxiliary predicate `SearchTree'` provides. This matter of compositionality is precisely why `SearchTree` is defined using an auxiliary inductive predicate `SearchTree'`, which is compositional (it can be, and is, defined in terms of itself).

Properties about recursive functions on trees mentioning `SearchTree` should first be generalized as more informative properties using `SearchTree'` so induction can go through. It will look like this:

```
Lemma insert_SearchTree' :
  forall t k0 v0   ???   ,
    SearchTree' ??? t ??? -> SearchTree' ??? (insert k0 v0 t) ???.
```

There are multiple valid ways of filling these "`???`" blanks. Coming up with new ones is a good exercise for the reader. One way that should work well here and many other situations is to put variables for all the missing arguments of predicates, and then figure out some suitable relation between them:

```
Lemma insert_SearchTree' :
  forall t k0 v0 lo hi lo' hi',
    ??? (* find a suitable assumption *) ->
    SearchTree' lo t hi -> SearchTree' lo' (insert k0 v0 t) hi'.
```

The relation should reflect the behavior of `insert`. What `insert` does, as far as those bounds are concerned, is to add the key `k0` to the tree, so the bounds must bound that, in addition to the rest of the tree:

```
Lemma insert_SearchTree' :
  forall t k0 v0 lo hi lo' hi',
    lo' <= lo -> hi <= hi' ->
    lo' <= k0 -> k0 < hi' ->
    SearchTree' lo t hi -> SearchTree' lo' (insert k0 v0 t) hi'.
```

Finally, since we're going to use `induction` on the `SearchTree' lo t hi` assumption, it's desirable to move most variables and hypotheses that it does not mention to the right, to strengthen the induction hypothesis further (as far as I can tell, this is always safe to do):

```
Lemma insert_SearchTree' :
  forall t k0 v0 lo hi,          (* k0 and v0 remain constant throughout the recursive applications of (insert k0 v0), so they can stay here (it would still be fine if they are moved with the rest). *)
    SearchTree' lo t hi -> 
    forall lo' hi',              (* The bounds are going to change at every step, so they move to the right of the inductive predicate. *)
      lo' <= lo -> hi <= hi' ->
      lo' <= k0 -> k0 < hi' ->
      SearchTree' lo' (insert k0 v0 t) hi'.
```

Proving this lemma and using it to prove `insert_SearchTree` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: One of the confusions I have is, in the base case of `insert_SearchTree'`, how to prove `S k0 <= hi'` with only   `H3 : k0 <= hi'` without changing the hypothesis from <= to <, in which case the induction step fails.  Othewise, I'm able to prove the lemma.  Thank you

Comment: I made a mistake :) It should be `k0 < hi'`.

Comment: Cool, so I'm literally one step away from completing the proof, but can you point out where I've made an error? Here is the complete code with that `admit` on line 155. https://gist.github.com/wmacmil/d9ad627a1bc721b02f5f67f308236afa

Comment: You already did the proof by induction on `SearchTree'` once, the point is to not do it again in the final theorem. After the first `induction H` to deconstruct `SearchTree` (line 102), you can do `intros k0 v0. pose proof (insert_SearchTree' t k0 v0 _ _ H).` to use the lemma, and now you have to guess some good values of `lo'` and `hi'`.